# Excel VBA pivot table change fields works in debug, error 1004 when executed

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I've gone through MANY posts. I think I know what the problem is, but not sure how to solve it. I don't know VBA very well. Through recording, cleaning, taking advice, etc. the below is what I have come up with. I have each sub set to its own button so that when you click one of the 7 days, whatever day field that was displayed is replaced with the selected day. Works occasionally, but always works in debug just fine. I think its because excel is trying to hide the first field "1 Sun" when it is already hidden. I think my solution would be to have it run a check to see what field is in position 8 and only hide that field (or run a very long string of "if" statements). I could really use some help on this one since my head hurts from all the beating against a wall.

```
    Option Explicit

Public Sub Sund()
    PreparePivot "1 Sun"
End Sub

Public Sub Mond()
    PreparePivot "2 Mon"
End Sub

Public Sub Tues()
    PreparePivot "3 Tue"
End Sub

Public Sub Wedn()
    PreparePivot "4 Wed"
End Sub

Public Sub Thur()
    PreparePivot "5 Thu"
End Sub

Public Sub Frid()
    PreparePivot "6 Fri"
End Sub

Public Sub Satu()
    PreparePivot "7 Sat"
End Sub


Private Sub PreparePivot(ByVal DayName As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CrewSheets") 
    
    With ws
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2 Mon").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("3 Tue").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("4 Wed").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("5 Thu").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("6 Fri").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("7 Sat").Orientation = xlHidden
        
        With .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(DayName) 

            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .position = 8
        End With
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_1_Sun").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_2_Mon").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_3_Tue").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_4_Wed").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_5_Thu").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_6_Fri").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_7_Sat").ClearManualFilter
        
        With .SlicerCaches("Slicer_" & Replace$(DayName, " ", "_")) 
            .SlicerItems("6am").Selected = True
            .SlicerItems("x").Selected = True
            .SlicerItems("off").Selected = False
            .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
            .SlicerItems("5th").Selected = True
            .SlicerItems("6th").Selected = True
            .SlicerItems("PTO").Selected = True
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Hat tip to [Peh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%E1%B4%87%CA%9C) for the help on the code thus far.

Comment: Ok, through lots of searching, I still haven't found out why my code gets error 1004 nearly every time. Since I think it's because the first field VBA is trying to hide is not always visible, I'm going to try hiding all fields (except the first) and then putting them back in. Not very elegant but it might be a solution. I'd rather just hide what ever field is in position = 8 (regardless of name) but I couldn't find how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so while trying to insert some other code to hide all fields so that the code can start fresh, I noticed there was a string of in the code that made me think "... hmmm, I wonder if..."  So I put just that one line of code in my ORIGINAL code (as shown in my question) and WHAM! it WORKED! Not sure why no one else came up with the solution since I am definitely a noob when it comes to VBA. What was the code?

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Duh!

Comment: This does run super slow sometimes. So, if someone has a better solution, I'd love to see it.